# socket.io to talk to server that is implementing RFC6455 in a strict fashion

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am trying to make my socket.io javascript client talk to a server implemented in cpp using websocketpp and its not working. Its surprising that I cant configure socket.io to fall back to real websockets when I need them.
Any one has any ideas or suggestions on this ? going back to websocket npm and re implementing my client is the only way ?

I tried this, but it does not work

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {
    transports: [
      'websocket',
      'polling'
    ]
});
```

Comment: I would simply write a websocket client in Javascript. The API is quite simple and It's very easy. I sometimes use [the client from the plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/99bbc16ed4ea434bb75da71a04490c298c5f9192/resources/client.js) and tweak it (I'm the original author, so I don't mind the fact that the code is somewhat messy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

socket.io is an additional protocol on top of webSocket so a socket.io client can ONLY talk to a socket.io server.  While socket.io uses webSocket for the transport, it needs support for it's additional layer on top of webSocket to work properly.

If you want to talk to a plain webSocket server, then you should use a plain webSocket client.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    socket.send('Hello Server!');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server', event.data);
});
```

You can probably find a socket.io server modules for cpp if you'd like to fix the server-side of things to talk socket.io.

Comment: @ak - Did this answer your question?

Comment: a year late in responding back, but ya it did help, I "downgraded" to a WebSocket client from socket.io client to talk to WebSocket based server